# How to pass a single element to a Class constructor when I have a group of elements on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, instance

I've been doing the research on Slack and elsewhere, but I am not able to find an answer to my question. I feel I lack some basic knowledge of OOP, which probably will take me hours of researching and coding before I get to the answer. But somehow I am perplexed that it might be such a complex issue.

The question is:
I have two buttons with the same class on a page (this is just for example). I create JS to handle the behaviour via Class function. In constructor I define an element I want the Class to point to, namely `child`. However, I want the Class to point to one of two `child` separately when clicking on them. However, `this.child` in constructor always points to two `child` elements.

Can you please help and tell what I am doing wrong?

```js
const selectors = {
 childElement: '.child'
},
$ = jQuery;

class Child {
  constructor() {
    this.child = $(selectors.childElement);
    this.bindUiEvents();
  }
  
  bindUiEvents() {
   $(this.child).on('click', this.addStyles);
  }
  
  addStyles() {
   $(this).addClass('coloured');
  }
}

new Child();
```

```css
.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.child.coloured {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
<button class="child">First</button>
<button class="child">Second</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You do know `$(selectors.childElement)` returns an array of the matching elements? So you'll always get more than one if there are more than one matches

Comment: Do you have any specific condition which object should point to which button.child?

Comment: Your making this more complicated than you need to, just use the selector, `$(selectors.childElement).on('click', this.addStyles);`, there is no advantage to storing the "child elements"

Comment: The code I posted is so simple for demonstration. I just need to learn how to do it using Classes to separate the logic for each instance of a Class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to create an instance of class `Child` for each button, you have to get the elements outside the class.

First we modify the Child class to accept a button during instantiation.

```
class Child {
  constructor(child) {
    this.child = child; //you would want to pass a single element here
    this.bindUiEvents();
  }

  bindUiEvents() {
    $(this.child).on('click', this.addStyles);
  }

  addStyles() {
    $(this.child).addClass('.coloured');
  }
}
```

Then we iterate each button outside

```
const buttons = $('.child');
const arry = []; //we'll put each Child instance here

//iterate on each button
buttons.each((idx, b) => {
   const clss = new Child(b); //pass each button element to their own Child class
   arry.push(clss); //add in arry for later access;
})
```

As @Liam said in the comments, you can do all of these without all this class-based jibber jabber. But I'm just gonna go assume you have other reasons for this extra complexities

Comment: I made a modification to the solution as actually, there is no need to pass value to an array. And also `each` requires two values, otherwise, the only one value is treated as index. I post the final code below (unfortunately I cannot post it in the comment :/)

Comment: @bakrall I have fixed `.each()`. I feel like it is not necessary to put your actual implementation of an answer derived from an accepted answer in this thread. You can go ahead and delete them. You can put out a comment to describe what you actually did.

Comment: @bakrall `I made a modification to the solution as actually, there is no need to pass value to an array.`. Actually there is; in 99% of cases, you will want future access to your instances. It is good practice to keep them within arms reach

Comment: Abana Clara, I followed your suggestion.